# No compile error when function returns variable of wrong type

Tags: c, gcc, lint

I have this `C` program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char foo()
{
    int x = 1000;
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("foo returns %d\n", foo());
}
```

I am using the following to compile it:

```
gcc -c -g -o ../tgt/Linux/main.c.o -Wall -fpic main.c
gcc ../tgt/Linux/main.c.o -g -o ../tgt/Linux/t -Wall
```

It generates the following output:

```
$ t
foo returns 232
```

This is the lower 8 bits of `x` in `foo()`.  So, it makes sense. But my question is: why didn't this generate a warning and is there a way for me to generate warnings for this type of mistake?

Comment: Compile using `-Wconversion` and you will notice a warning

Comment: @AlterMann Thanks man. I wonder why is in not triggered when both using -`pedantic` `-Wall` `-Wextra`.

Comment: A char is a small integer in C. You will not get any error unless you use -Wconversion flag as @AlterMann said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comment you mentioned :

> I wonder why is in not triggered when both using -pedantic -Wall
>   -Wextra.

`-Wall` doesn't turn  on the `-Wconversion` flag [[1]](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Neither `-Wpedantic` nor `-pedantic` would catch

```
return x; // This is valid as per strict ISO C
```

In fact `-pedantic` would just check for any GNU C extensions [[2]](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~fsalvi/docs/gcc/www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_27.html).

For example if you compile below stuff:

```
int a=10;
int b[a]; // This is invalid as per strict ISO C
```

with `-pedantic`, gcc should give you :

```
 warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘b’ [-Wvla]
```

So the only option is to use `-Wconversion` explicitly while compiling.

```
gcc -Wconversion main.c -o main
```